# using App script to access full google logs

Tags: logging, google-apps-script, google-admin-sdk, audit-logging

I'm working on a script that audits the full google logs.  Google retains 450 days (14.7 months) of logs however they only make 6 months available in console, so I'm working on a script to pull from the full 14.7 months.  I reached out to google support to see how best to do it and they recommended using api calls.

https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/reference/userUsageReport

I have a script that can now pull 6 months, but I'm not sure how to extend it to the full 14 months that google logs. I tried changing the start date but It looks liked it maybe more complex.

```
function getData () {
  var now = new Date();
  var fourhundredfiftydaysago = new Date(now.getTime() - 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 450);
  var startTime= fourhundredfiftydaysago.toISOString();
  var apps_list = ['admin', 'calendar', 'drive', 'groups', 'gplus', 'login', 'mobile', 'rules', 'token'];
  var userKey = 'all';
  var optionalArgs = {startTime: startTime};

  for (i = 0; i < apps_list.length; i++){
    var applicationName = apps_list[i];
    var response = AdminReports.Activities.list(userKey, applicationName, optionalArgs)
    var activities = response.items;

    if (activities && activities.length > 0) {
      Logger.log(apps_list[i] + ':');
      for (x = 0; x < activities.length; x++) {
        var activity = activities[x];
        Logger.log('%s: %s (%s)', activity.id.time, activity.actor.email, activity.events[0].name, activity.ipAddress);
      }
    }
    else {
      Logger.log(apps_list[i] + ':')
      Logger.log('No logs found.');
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What's your specific question? Are you getting errors? If so, why haven't you said what they are? Does it not work? Note that "not work" is **extremely** ambiguous, so you should specify exactly what your script does, and how what it does do, does not meet your criteria for "it works".

Comment: Also note that your current function will only report the first page of results, because you dont page through the list (by requerying with the page token from the most recent result set).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example, you're querying `AdminReports.Activites` not `AdminReports.UserUsageReports`.

The latter is the documentation you linked to. If you look at [the documentation for `AdminReports.Activities`](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/reference/activities), all of the application reports have a maximum time period of 180 days.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I was wondering how then should I implement a get request in app script, I've looked around but I can't find a use case that makes sense to me, the documentation is something that I'm struggling to make applicable.

Comment: Given the API distinction detailed in my answer, you're not being clear in what you're asking for. Can you specify which API you're interested in interacting with (i.e. [UserUsageReports](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/reference/userUsageReport) vs [Activities](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/reference/activities))?